# ASP.NET conditional validation on custom control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have an `.aspx` page with two `.ascx` controls on it and two radiobuttons next to them toggling between the two, so that the user only fills one of them.

These controls are Nib/Iban fields:

- the nib field has four textboxes in it and two validators for each textbox and two validators for the field(10 in total)
- the iban field has five textboxes, but the first has no validation, in it and two validators for each textbox and two validators for the field(10 in total)

I have the nib field selected by default(i select the correspondent radiobutton and do nib.Enable=true;iban.Enable=false in my page_load)

I use jquery to enable one or the other

In my overridden `Validate` method, depending on which radiobutton is selected, I do `iban.Enable=true;nib.Enable=false`

The question is no matter how I do it it only validates the default field (in this case only the nib gets validated), how make it so it validates only the selected control in server side and in client side?

Comment: It's better to include the code you're working on in your post or in a fiddle...

Comment: code please, what you have tried.